# ProtoBuf is not serializing a field in inherited class

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I have a base class called `PrivilegeType` and it's inherited by various other classes.
Everything works fine except for one specific field called `PossibleValues` which doesn't get serialized/deserialized well.

**Base class definition:**

```
[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(13, typeof(PrivilegeEnum))]
public abstract class PrivilegeType {
...
}
```

**`PrivilegeEnum` definition:**

```
[ProtoContract]
public class PrivilegeEnum : PrivilegeEnumLike<PrivilegeEnumValue> {
...
}
```

**`PrivilegeEnumLike<T>` definition:**

```
[ProtoContract]
public abstract class PrivilegeEnumLike<T> : PrivilegeType<T>
{
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public Dictionary<string, PrivilegeEnumValue> PossibleValues;
    ...
}
```

**`PrivilegeEnumValue` definition:**

```
[ProtoContract]
public class PrivilegeEnumValue
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string Value;
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string Text;
    [ProtoMember(3)]
    public HashSet<PrivilegeEnumValue> ImpliedValues = new HashSet<PrivilegeEnumValue>();
    ...
}
```

The thing is, that field is defined in`PrivilegeEnumLike<T>` which is not included in `ProtoInclude` list itself, but its subclasses are. I can't add `PrivilegeEnumLike<>` to `ProtoInclude` list because I guess it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the rule:

**Class hierarchy must be implemented correctly.
This means you need to use `ProtoInclude` on *parent* classes, NOT necessarily *base* classes**
Otherwise, any inherited class between your subclass and baseclass will *not* get serialized.

*What I did:*

**Base class:**

```
[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(12, typeof(PrivilegeEnumLike<PrivilegeEnumValue>))]
[ProtoInclude(13, typeof(PrivilegeEnumLike<PrivilegeEnumValue[]>))]
public abstract class PrivilegeType
```

**Middle class:**

```
[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(20, typeof(PrivilegeEnum))]
[ProtoInclude(21, typeof(PrivilegeEnumSet))]
public abstract class PrivilegeEnumLike<T> : PrivilegeType<T>
```

Everything works correctly now.
Please let me know if there's any better solution to this.